# Deserialize .net object in Java

Tags: java, .net, serialization, deserialization

To aid our users we would like to make our Java-based desktop product auto-configure itself to work with the text-based file output of a .NET-based third-party application. To do this, I'm trying to read the preferences from the third-party product to determine where it stores its output files.

The preferences seem to be stored in a binary-format .NET serialised object. I'm guessing this is the case because the binary file contains the following, starting at byte 18:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, ... ,[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ...
```

I don't know much about .NET - Java is my thing. But I'm guessing this indicates that the file contains a dictionary of strings mapped to objects.

My googling has failed to turn up a clear description of the .NET serialization format.

Assuming that I've already read the entire file into an array of bytes, how can I decode the byte array into something useful, using Java?

```
public Object decode(byte[] ary) {
     // help me here?
}
```

or better

```
public Map<String, String> decode(byte[] ary) {
     // help me here?
}
```

(Ideally the third-party vendor would make this info available in a clearly-documented text format. But as they are a separate company, I can't influence their development schedule).

Comment: IMHO, even if you get this working, it will be very error prone. I would go every effort to convince folks that this is not the way to do.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to how you are serializing. If you are using `BinaryFormatter`, I would suggest: *stop now*! You could *possibly* make it work if you tried hard and long enough, but it would be brittle and frankly not worth the effort. There are multiple cross-platform binary serialization libraries available for both Java and .NET: your best bet would be to pick one of those, and use *that* for your serialization.

`BinaryFormatter` is *rarely* a good choice even for .NET-based code; it is *never* a good choice for cross-platform code.

Comment: @Mark, I'm not serializing - a third party is, and I have no control over their choices.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod you could, however, presumably deserialize it via whatever API they provide, and re-serialize the data in a different - more suitable - choice ;p Also: have you tried simply asking them what serializer they are using?